# How to select data from db using angular variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I want to write select query in php to get data from database using variable from front-end. In other words I need to do something like this:
    SELECT email FROM users WHERE token = '$token'
What I currently have, I have code which posts my variables to back end:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http,$templateCache) {
    $scope.subscribe = function (gameId){
        $scope.codeStatus = "";
        $http({
            url: "php/test.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUserInfo')),
                gameId: gameId,
                token:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            cache: $templateCache
        }).success(function(response) {
            $scope.codeStatus = response.data; 
            console.log(response);
        });

    };

});
```

And here is my php code:

```
<?php
$lnk = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
    or die ('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('pitch', $lnk) or die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$token=$data->token;   

$dump1 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users where token = '$token' ");

if(!$dump1) exit("Error - ".mysql_error()); 
$getList = array(); 
$outp = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dump1)) { 
    $relations = array();
    $getList[] = $row;
}
$output = json_encode(array('users' => $getList));

echo $output; 
?>
```

The weirdest thing for me is that when I try to go to url localhost/php/test.php I get an Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php/test.php on line 8, which means I guess that $token is empty, but when I console.log(response) in angular it shows me my token in console which I think means that data from front-end was passed to back-end. Or my understanding is wrong?

Will be really thankful for help!

Comment: The problem was solved by using cookies instead of trying to get data from local storage.

Answer (score 2):

first thing is try to var_dump($_POST), or try to var_dump($data) on your test.php